# How to make multiple sheets as range for Summary page in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I created a timesheet to track items that completed by staffs per month and in the timesheet there are 31 tabs/sheets named as 1,2,3, .. act as dates in a month. Then there's summary page.

In Summary Page, I would like to use the dates (tabs) as a variable range between two dates and show sum between these dates (tabs).

I spent 3 hours searching for this and there are no identical cases like mine for me to refer.

Appreciate if someone can guide me on this. 
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question isn't exactly clear what you are doing on your summary page. Is this what you are looking for - [How do I create a summary of the same few cells on many different sheets in Excel 2013?](http://superuser.com/q/929332/97028)?

Comment: Can you clarify by providing an example. In particular, refer to a cell in your summary sheet and explain what you would have the formula in that cell do. In your explanation of that formula describe the cells and sheets it references as an example.

Comment: Have you tried to use the SUM formula at all? Click on the cell you want to enter the sum, type =sum, then select the formula, then click on each page and cell to sum up. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to ranges across sheets by having them right next to each other and using e.g. `SUM(1:31!A1)` as the sum of every cell `A1` in every sheet from `1` to `31`.

Comment: Nice trick. I didn't know that one existed in that context. I tested it and worked like a charm Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, with summary on Sheet4. =SUM(Sheet1:Sheet3!A1)